# Displaying a hidden div is slow in phonegap after a tap event

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing a webapp using phonegap for android .I m using jquery mobile tap event and for each tap event i want to show a loading div before displaying the content.I am seeing a delay between the tap event and display of loading div.
Below is snippet of the code I have written

```
    $('#events').bind('tap',function () {           
        document.getElementById("loadingDiv").style.display = "block";  
       });
```

and this my loadingDiv

```
<div id="loadingDiv"></div>

#loadingDiv {position: fixed; background:black url('images/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat center 20%; height:100%; width:100%; z-index:100000;}
```

And also for speeding up the Jquery mobile I have turned off the transitions as well.

Please guide me on How to display the loadingDiv immediately for a nice user experience.

Comment: you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Y6yEW/

Comment: What is the difference between the tap event and click event? I also developed Anroaid application in phonegap, and I used regular events such as MouseDown / Up etc, it worked quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the jQuery mobile tap event is being called correctly.  It sounds like an issue with the browser taking a while to actually display to element.

Due to 'display: none' [not being included in the render tree](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Render_tree_construction), when you change it to block the browser can take a while to do this.

Some solutions are setting the element to 'opacity: 0' and the setting it to 'opacity: 1' (alternative being the visibility property).  Doing this will mean the element will affect the layout, but since you are using a fixed position this should not be an issue.